# user input to break from a for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, console-application

How would I go about using, for example, the letter "q" to break from the for loop. When I try the executing the following code I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type int to int[]"

```
private static void EnterNumber()
        {
            int[] numbers = new int[8];
            int q = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                Write("Enter in an integer value or the letter q to quit: ");
                numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
                if (numbers = q)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: For an equals test, you need to use ==, not a single one. But that doesn't help you converting a character Q into a number

Comment: Why did you just delete your latest question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940739/why-am-i-getting-the-error-implicitly-converting-type-double-to-an-int

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void EnterNumber()
                {
                    int[] numbers = new int[8];
                    int q = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Write("Enter in an integer value or the letter q to quit: ");
                        var value = ReadLine();
                        int parsedInt;
                        if (int.TryParse(value, out parsedInt))
                        {
                            numbers[i] = value;
                        }
                        else if (value == "q")
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            WriteLine("Unexpected input.");
                         }
                    }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter in an integer value or the letter q to quit: ");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^-[0-9]+$|^[0-9]+$").IsMatch(input))
        numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(input);
    else if (input == "q")
        break;
}
```