# Why am I getting the error implicitly converting type double to an int?

Tags: c#, class, return

How do I fix the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). I don't see where I am changing an int to a double. Here's the following code I am working with:

```
namespace Chapter_9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Circle create = new Circle();
            create.SetRadius(2);
            WriteLine("Radius = {0}", create.GetRadius());
            WriteLine("Diameter = {0}", create.GetDiameter());
            WriteLine("Area = {0}", create.GetArea());
        }
    }
    class Circle
    {
        private int Radius;
        private readonly int Diameter;
        private readonly double Area;

        public Circle()
        {
            CircleRadius = 1;
        }
        public int CircleRadius { get; set; }
        public int GetRadius()
        {
            return Radius;
        }
        public void SetRadius(int radius)
        {
            Radius = radius;
        }
        public int GetDiameter()
        {
            int Diameter = Radius * 2;
            return Diameter;
        }
        public int GetArea()
        {
            double Area = Radius * Radius * Math.PI;
            return Area; <--------- !!!!ERROR IS HERE!!!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not changing "an int to a double". You're changing a `double` to an `int`. You need `return (int)Area;`.

Comment: Perhaps, though, the issue is that you're using `int` to measure things that would naturally be `double` in the first place.

Comment: And also, you seem to be doing Java-like coding in c#. Why not use properties rather than the `Set` and `Get` methods?

Comment: @Enigmativity I have tried that, but it returns all values as whole numbers and I need exact values. Like eg 3 x 3.5 = 10.50, but if I'm returning it as an int it returns the number as 10. I need it to return as 10.50 as the final output.

Comment: @Enigmativity am I not allowed to return values that are doubles?

Comment: "I need exact values" - you'd better read [this](https://floating-point-gui.de/).

Answer (score 3):

As you said, your main problem is that you want precise decimal calculation over integers. Yet your return type of `public int GetArea()` is `int`. To fix your immediate problem - just change its type to double and that will be it!

However there are a couple of other improvements you can make.
First of all - you have `public int CircleRadius { get; set; }` that is not used. Then, as @Enigmativity said you are writing this in Java style. Use autoproperties a bit more, it will be much easier. And take note of your fields - you declared them but have not used...

Here is a cleaned up class:

```
class Circle
{
    public double Radius {get; set;}
    public double Diameter 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return Radius * 2;
        }
    }
    public double Area
    { 
        get 
        {
            return Radius * Radius * Math.PI;
        }
    }

    public Circle()
    {
        this.Radius = 1;
    }
}
```

And your main would be

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Circle create = new Circle();
    create.Radius = 2;
    WriteLine("Radius = {0}", create.Radius);
    WriteLine("Diameter = {0}", create.Diameter);
    WriteLine("Area = {0}", create.Area);
}
```

Comment: Dont be! Everyone make mistakes that feel stupid later! That is called learning! :)

Comment: I'd replace the `int`s to `double`s across the board.

Comment: Updated. Just was keeping it as close to OP example as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you intended to return a `double`, but you declared your method as returning `int`.

Comment: I didn't realize this. I feel stupid for even posting this now..

Comment: @itsAvenius - Don't feel bad. That's what this site is for - to help developers, at all levels, to learn.